# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 15.04, partitioning

I have Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 running. I wanted to upgrade to 15.04, but the upgrade manager doesn't give that option. I tried [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)
but, it gives me a 404 error. How do i upgrade without affecting the existing partitions on my system adversely.

ANSWER: 12.04 isn't an EOL release. Thanks Arronicle and frkaiem for pointing it out

Comment: You cannot upgrade 12.04 to 15.04, or at least if you do you are on your own as it is not officially supported. You can upgrade it to 14.04, however, and from 14.04 you can upgrade to 16.04 when it is released in a couple months.

Comment: How do i upgrade it to 14.04?

Comment: You can find upgrade instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10).

Comment: the upgrade manager doesn't suggest 14.04 as an option. It only gives 12.10 as an option, if i set the  settings, "notify me of new updates" to "For newer versions"

Comment: This is a different question, so you should probably open a new question (*i.e.*, why does Update Manager not give the option to upgrate to 14.04). I am not running a 12.04 desktop, but on a 12.04 server I get the upgrate to 14.04 when running `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my question statement'

Comment: Uh, no, I see nothing of the sort in your question above.

Comment: I have Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 running. I wanted to upgrade to 15.04, but the upgrade manager doesn't give that option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way is to:

1. download the iso image of the version you like (15.10)
2. create a bootable USB stick with this image
3. If /home is not on a separate partition, make a backup of /home on a separate disk.
4. Boot  from the USB stick you just prepared and choose install.
5. If /home is not on a separate partition just go ahead and erase the old one and install the new one. If /home is on separate partition choose "do something else" and manually assign where root and /home are.
6. Install the software
7. After you first reboot you may want to compare what you have in the /home and in your backup (of /home). Probably restoring the backup will do (no guarantee though).
8. let me know if this works

Comment: How do I find out if /home is on a separate partition?  what do you mean by boot from a usb stick? I got the part where i have to create a bootable usb stick